# Inequality join in hive

Tags: apache, hive

I know hive doesn't support inequal joins and can you please help me to get another solution for the below.

select * from A a join B b on a.id=b.id and

a.date < b.date.

Thanks Inadvance.

Answer (score 1):

In-equal join support not yet available , but how about:

```
select * from A a join B b on a.id=b.id where  
a.date < b.date;
```

Comment: What do you do when you don't have a common field like `id` and you just want to join on date inequality? Is this possible: 
`select * from A a join B b where a.date < b.date;`?

Comment: @NurShomik I really would like to know too but seems this is an open question for some time